# Why we say Riemann zeta function and not Euler zeta function?

Tags: math-history, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I'm confused zeta function was introduced in the first by the Swiss mathematician Leonhard Euler in 1737  and it were extend by Riemann to the complex plane , But Why the name " zeta function " refer to Riemann and not Euler however the first who is discovred it is Euler not Riemann ?

Comment: FYI, in case you weren't aware of the site, in the future you may consider whether or not the SE [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) site might be a more appropriate place to ask questions like this.

Comment: Because enough stuff is named after Euler. (Non-serious answer for the record.)

Comment: When one says that Riemann extended the zeta function to the complex plane and it's no big deal is quite similar to saying that Einstein extended Newton's theory of gravitation to high speeds and energies using Galileo's theory of moving frames so why do we call Einstein's theory of relativity and not Galileo-Newton's theory of gravitation while in reality the simple fact of the extension is highly non-trivial even today, not to speak in 1850 or so when Riemann did it

Comment: @Eevee and lots of other stuff is named after Riemann - Riemann surfaces, Cauchy-Riemann equations, Riemann's famous theorem on conditionally convergent series, Riemann's theory of trigonometric series which is quite interesting, Riemann integrals, Riemann's "other function" , Riemannian metric etc...

Answer (score 1):

The term "Riemann zeta function" refers to a function whose domain is $\mathbb C$ (unless you want to say it's $\mathbb C\smallsetminus\{1\}$ so that its value is everywhere finite). If Euler only studied its restriction to the interval $(1,+\infty)$ and nobody before Riemann extended its domain like that, then the conventional name makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,But in logic if you discovred any function whatever its kind and after you researchers build their work on it , Is it in fact that function should take your name ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik : There is no justice, rationality, or honesty in naming concepts after people. Weierstrass never had anything to do with the tangent half-angle substitution that people call the Weierstrass substitution, and authors of calculus textbooks ignorantly assert that he introduced it. It was used by Euler, who died before Weierstrass was born. Pell never had anything to do with Pell's equation.